# False debt on credit report, original creditor bankrupt/ out of business multiple fraud lawsuits filed against them in state

Tags: fraud

I recently discovered a collections on my credit report, over $4000 U.S. 
The original creditor was a now defunct property management company.
They are notorious here in Idaho for evading with over $1 million dollars of fraudulently gained monies
I spoke to legal aid at v.a. Boise and they said I have a good case ?
How do I proceed in clearing my credit report ?
Please and thank you
Mr. Tower

Answer (score 1):

> How do I proceed in clearing my credit report ?

Regardless of whether you retain an attorney on this matter, I suggest you to get acquainted with the [Fair Credit Reporting Act, 15 U.S.C. § 1681 *et seq.*](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/chapter-41/subchapter-III), as it addresses the issue of correcting inaccurate credit reports.

Also search for [court opinions](http://www.leagle.com/leaglesearch?exact=fair%20credit%20reporting%20act) involving the FCRA to get a better sense of how the Act is interpreted/applied.

Please note that this answer is rather generic. The creditor's alleged history of fraud and the fact that now it is a defunct company add complexity or uncertainty on how to proceed in your particular case.